# How to rotate the table into 'landscape' from 'portrait' format

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xquery

In the example below we are trying to rotate the table into 'landscape' with Microsoft Word using 'XSLT 1.0' and follow the steps below:

**Step 1)** Open the XML file in Microsoft Word (i.e. It will be open in the text format)

**Step 2)** Browse the XSLT file from the XML Data views (i.e. Data will be rendered after applying xslt).

Can anyone help us.

**INPUT XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1990</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Eros</title>
    <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>BMG</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>One night only</title>
    <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1998</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
    <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS</company>
    <price>8.10</price>
    <year>1973</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Maggie May</title>
    <artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Pickwick</company>
    <price>8.50</price>
    <year>1990</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Romanza</title>
    <artist>Andrea Bocelli</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.80</price>
    <year>1996</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
    <artist>Percy Sledge</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Atlantic</company>
    <price>8.70</price>
    <year>1987</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Black angel</title>
    <artist>Savage Rose</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Mega</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1995</year>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Artist</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="price > 10">
                                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
                                </td>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is your XSLT transformation something else than what you want? With other words: What do yo get? What do you want?

Comment: @Pierre François, I want to display table in landscape. We are converting xml to word using xslt.

Comment: Can you try the XSLT code below? I think it is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand and guess correctly your question, i.e. transforming a portrait table into a landscape one, next XSLT code will get the job done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32">Title</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
              <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32">Artist</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="price > 10">
                  <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
                    <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
                  </td>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Obviously, I didn't use Microsoft Word to test this code. I applied directly the XSLT code to the XML input, producing HTML output. Why should I use a screwdriver to open a door instead of a key, even if this sometimes works? Take the right tool for the right use.